# firewalld rules to allow static IP SSH access with backdoor?

Tags: centos, ssh, firewalld

I'm new to `firewalld` and `centos 7`.
I read other questions and I've learned about "zones" and rules.
Right now, it's in the default state:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
public

# firewall-cmd --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ftp ssh
  ports: 21/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Every couple of days I log in via SSH and the system tells me there were 20,000+ of failed log in attempts. It's time to set up the firewall!

My needs:

- allow SSH access only from a specific IP address
- but how to handle the unlikely event if my IP will change in the future *before* I can release this setting?
- allow HTTP and HTTPS web services (port 80 and 443) from any address
- block everything else

I kindly ask an help to understand how to approach this scenario - and of course if it makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. whitelist a few IP addresses if that is feasible for you
2. brute force attacks against machines exposed on the Internet are a fact of life, tools like Fail2ban, CSF+LFD will help a lot
3. you could set up a **VPN** on your server (or somewhere else if it is part of a larger infrastructure), then whitelist the VPN private IP range (eg 10.* 172.*)
4. you could set up **port knocking** to make the SSH port stealth

Given that you seem to have a webserver and perhaps FTP, I think option #2 would be appropriate and will protect services other than SSH. You can combine more options depending on your requirements.

Regarding the webserver, a WAF (web application firewall) may be desirable too.